# jQuery image src not changing

Tags: html, jquery, css

Can someone help me with this? I am changing image on image click. When I do it without animation it works fine but transition is jerky.

```
<script>
  $("#thumbs img").click(function() {
    $("#mainImage").attr('src',$(this).attr('src').replace('thumbnails','ovado').replace('png','jpg'));
  })
</script>
```

But when I add some animation script animation works but every time same image loads. Please see the code below and try to help me if you can.

```
<script>
  $("#thumbs img").click(function() {
      $("#mainImage").fadeOut(1000, function() {
          $("#mainImage").attr('src',$('#thumbs img').attr('src').replace('thumbnails','ovado').replace('png','jpg'));
      }).fadeIn(1000);
      return false;
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Wondering why the first one is `$(this)` and the second one is `$('#thumbs img')`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can only assume there are multiple img's inside of `#thumbs`. You'll want to pass the element as you were doing before, into the your next function.

- `$(this)` in your first snippet represented the image you were clicking
- By referencing it inside the click the function, you are able to pass it the `fadeOut` function

I showed an example of what I assume is what you're trying to accomplish.  You'll want to add back the `replace` function.

```js
var $thumbImgs = $("#thumbs img");
var $mainImg = $("#mainImage");
$thumbImgs.click(function() {
  var $imgClicked = $(this);
  $mainImg.fadeOut(1000, function() {
    $mainImg.attr('src', $imgClicked.attr('src'));
  }).fadeIn(1000);
});
```

```css
#mainImage {
  max-width: 200px;
}
#thumbs li {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 100px;
}
#thumbs li img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="mainImage" src="https://placekitten.com/g/500/500">
<ul id="thumbs">
  <li>
    <img src="https://placekitten.com/g/200/300">
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="https://placekitten.com/g/400/300">
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="https://placekitten.com/g/500/300">
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: How I can add sliding animation instead of fading?

Comment: @JamalEjaz are you trying to create a slider? or did you mean the `slideToggle` function?

Comment: I mean instead of fade transition effect if I want to slide images from left to right or top to bottom. I just want want to change animation effect.